# Why does standalone class with varwidth option give different outputs with pdftex and luatex?

Tags: standalone

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  x
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `pdftex`, I get:

[image]

Compiling with `luatex`, I get:

[image]

Do I miss something or is this a bug?

As a side note, the images above are produced by the `convert` option of the `standalone` class as stated in the manual:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,convert={size=640}]{standalone}
```

Strangely enough, Imagemagick's `convert` produces the exact opposite of what can be seen in my `pdf` viewer (that is the above image showing what happens with `pdftex` is the `luatex` `convert` output and vice versa).

Comment: which version of luatex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)`

Comment: Oh OK the old one, I asked as anything to do with back end settings like page size is fundamentally incompatible between 0.80 (which is like pdftex) and 0.95 (as in miktex and texlive 2016 tests) (which isn't like pdftex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I see it in luatex 0.95 to (with luatex85 naturally), and one can avoid standalone, simply varwidth with an equation in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

varwidth works by putting everything in a box (a minipage), then removes the outer hull, and measures the width of the content.

The problem is that the equation gives a different width for pdflatex and lualatex. Compile this file and then inspect the log-files (`\eqno` is the primitive which prints the number):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setbox0=\vbox{$$ x \eqno{x} $$}
\showoutput\showbox0      
\end{document}
```

With pdflatex the display math gives this hbox:

```
.\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x175.35764, shifted 169.64236
```

This is a rather small box, shifted to the right. This shift gets lost, when varwidth measures the content.

With lualatex (I used 0.95 for the test) one gets

```
 .\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x345.0, direction TLT
 ..\kern169.64236
```

This is a larger box with a kern in it, which doesn't gets lost.

So the problem lies in a different handling of display math with a number on the engine level. I doubt that the luatex maintainer will change this, and varwidth imho has no chance to remove the additional space. So you will have to avoid numbered equations if you want identical output ...

Comment: Indeed: we discussed some of this with Hans and the changes in box shifting for math mode are 'by design'.